# Clean-up unreferenced configs and secrets in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-secrets

After some time of creating and removing stacks and services on my Docker Swarm cluster, the lists returned by `docker config ls` and `docker secret ls` are quite extensive. However, a lot of the listed configs and secrets are outdated leftovers from previous deployments and not referenced anymore by any running service.

Is there any quick equivalent to [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) which will clean-up the config and secret stores from unreferenced items?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to easily remove them.
My current solution to prune all unused configs is:

docker config rm $(docker config ls -q)